# Excel HTTP Get Timeout

Tags: excel, vba

We have this little sub which simply pumps data into a remote server.  All is working as expected.

The other day, there was an incident on the web server which lasted about an hour.  I could still PING the server, but IIS was non-responsive.  As a result, the macro just hanged waiting for a response.

Any thoughts on a quick pass/fail test or timeout?

```
Sub WebLog(getUser As String, getEvent As String, getValue As String)
    Dim URL As String
    URL = "http://myurl.com/dp.aspx?Task=Log&v1=" + getUser + "&v2=" + getEvent + "&v3=" + getValue
    Dim xml As Object
    Set xml = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    xml.Open "GET", URL, False
    xml.Send
End Sub
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You may want to take a look at the `WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1` library, which lets you set `timeouts` for your requests.

> [WinHttpRequest object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384106(v=vs.85).aspx)

You should set `.SetTimeouts` before `.Open` and the four parameters you set for `.SetTimeouts` are (in milliseconds):

```
Resolve, Connect, Send and Receive
```

Your sample code would be (for 10 second timeout):

```
Sub WebLog(getUser As String, getEvent As String, getValue As String)
    Dim URL As String
    URL = "http://myurl.com/dp.aspx?Task=Log&v1=" + getUser + "&v2=" + getEvent + "&v3=" + getValue
    Dim xml As Object
    Set xml = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    xml.SetTimeouts 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000
    xml.Open "GET", URL, False
    xml.Send
End Sub
```

Comment: FABULOUS - Knew there had to be a timeout.  Expect a bounty as soon as the system lets me

Comment: Never undstood why we can't create a bounty from day 1.