# Excel VBA MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0 operation timed out

Tags: excel, vba, xmlhttprequest, plumber, msxml2

My Excel VBA-code below calls a local server on my computer although sometimes it stops and gives the following error :

```
Run-time error '2147012894 (80072ee2)': The operation timed out.
```

This is the Excel VBA code:

```
Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
http.Open "GET", myurl, False
http.send
```

The error occurs at line http.send.

I am not sure why the error occurs. I have 4 Excel instances running at once. All calling the local server once a minute.

I would like to solve the issue in order to keep the code running after the error.

I can find several posts about MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0 although since I am not familiair with it I do not succeed to implement a solution.

Thanks a lot!

**UPDATE 1:**

I have modified my code in this way:

```
Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")

http.Open "GET", myurl, False, "", ""
http.send
If http.readyState = 4 Then
'Debug.Print http.responseText
Else: Debug.Print "xmlhttp.ReadyState =" & http.readyState
End If


'*** process received JSON-response in code below 
Set JSON = ParseJson(http.responseText)
```

Although if I turn off the local server, the code still stops at line `http.send`

I have modified the code in this way:

**UPDATE 2:**

```
Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")

    minute_to_wait_api = 50
    flag_api = True
    starttime_api = Timer

    http.Open "GET", myurl, False, "", ""
    http.send

    Do
        DoEvents
        DoEvents
        endtime_api = Timer
        endtime_api = Round(endtime_api - starttime_api, 0)
        If endtime_api >= minute_to_wait_api Then
            flag_api = False
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop While http.readyState <> 4
    
    If flag_api = False Then
      Debug.Print "API Taking too long to respond"
      Exit Sub
    End If
            
    If http.Status <> 200 Then
        Debug.Print "http_error: " & http.Status
        Exit Sub
    End If
```

Comment: Please, try: `http.Open "GET", myurl, False, "", ""` `http.Send` `If http.ReadyState = 4 Then` `Debug.Print http.responseText` `Else` `Debug.Print "xmlhttp.ReadyState =" & http.ReadyState` `End If`.

Comment: @ FaneDuru Thank you! I will implement this and let you know if it solves the issue.

Comment: @ FaneDuru In update 1 in the post above I have implemented your code. Can you please check if this is the correct way? If I turn off the local server it still stops at line http.send. Although I don't know if this is a good test since maybe it is not an identical situation like the time-out issue.

Comment: Do you use any credentials when you manually connect to the server in discussion?

Comment: I don't use any password or username. I use this call : myurl = "127.0.0.1:1234/return?symbol=" & goof. This local API is launched with Plumber from R.

Comment: Unfortunately I still have the initial error as well: Run-time error : The operation timed out.

Comment: If i understand correctly my issue is caused by waiting too long for a response from the local server. I read in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49826217/excel-http-get-timeout that the waiting time can be set. Maybe I should set it to a very long time like 300 seconds with this line of code http.setTimeouts 300000, 300000, 300000, 300000. Although I don't know if this make sense.

Comment: It is very improbable to have such a problem. This is happening when try accessing something on the internet, having a bad connection or the respective site has a problem. Anyhow, if you think that this is your problem you can start a loop" `Do while http.ReadyState = 4` `DoEvents` `Loop`. If this is not the case, in order to avoid staying in an infinite loop, you can declar a variable ('i as Long') to be incremented inside the loop after a second (using `Wait`) and finally place something as: `If i >= 10 Then MsgBox "Nothing after 10 attempts": Exit Do`. Even increase that 10 cases...

Comment: Thank you for this solution! In R I call an API server from the internet. In R I have I set up a local server which is feeded with data from the API. In case the internetserver cannot reached for some time, my code in R gives a http 503-error, although it keeps running and keeps trying to call the API. Although in that case the time-out error occurs in VBA. I don't know why. It is hard to replicate the situation.

Comment: Not sure I can get you... Is it the called server the one behaving as you try explaining above, or is just an example about something else?

Comment: It is not an example about something else. I have a script in R which calls an internet-api. This R script processes the data and sends the processed data to a local server on my pc. This local server is reached (called) from a script in VBA. The script in VBA throws the error above if the script in R has a 503-error. Although in this case the script in R keeps running and tries to reach the api again. Although it causes the script in VBA to stop while giving the error 'operation timed out'.

Comment: @ FaneDuru I have added your modification in the code in my post above. Please see Update 2. It is not exactly as you mentioned since it is pretty tough for me to implement your suggestions since I am not very familiar with DoEvents. I found this code in Update 2 above and if I understand correctly it is similar to the code you suggested. I will let it run now to check if it solves the issue. I will let you know the outcome. Thanks!