How to use Excel VBA to check if a website is down?
I try to use the codes in this post to open a website in Excel VBA. However, even the website is down, the ShellExecute will still return success, as below:

So I just wonder if there is a way to check whether the website is down or not in VBA?

Have a look at
https://gist.github.com/ikudosi/843fb65678a4e46911aa

You can make a HEAD request with a timeout and see if there's a response: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49826355/478884

Here is one possible approach. This is basic code to get you started - you will need to add further validation etc, and even then it's likely to be somewhat brittle (but the same is true of almost any approach for this kind of problem).
Public Sub OpenUrl()

Dim req As Object

Set req = CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
url = "https://www.google.com"
req.Open "HEAD", url

Err.Clear
On Error GoTo HandleError

req.Send
MsgBox "Success"
Exit Sub

HandleError:
MsgBox "Error: " + vbNewLine + CStr(Err.Number) + vbNewLine + Err.Description
Err.Clear

End Sub

If you run this code as provided, it should display the success message.
If you change the URL to, say, "https://www.google2.com", an error message should be displayed instead.
To actually open the website in a browser, you will of course still need to send the ShellExecute command as before, having verified the response from the website.
(In case it isn't clear, the reason your original code wasn't working as desired is that the ShellExecute command was considered to have succeeded once the URL had been passed to the browser. The fact that the website couldn't be accessed is outside of Excel's remit.)

I played with the answer of @NeilT. So the solution is at him. I have extended his solution by getting the http status code:
Sub getHTTPStatus()

  Dim url As String
  Dim result As String
  Dim state As Long
  
  With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
    url = "https://www.google.com"  ' HTTP 200   --> success
    'url = "https://www.google"      ' HTTP 12007 --> inofficial http status
    'url = "https://www.amazon.de/Cryptonomicon-Roman-Neal-Stephenson-ebook/dp/"  ' HTTP 404 --> client error
    .Open "HEAD", url
    On Error Resume Next
    .Send
    state = .Status
    result = "Error: " + vbNewLine + CStr(Err.Number) + vbNewLine + Err.Description
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    Select Case state
      ' HTTP status groups: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes
      Case Is >= 600: result = result & vbNewLine & "An inofficial error occoured"
      Case Is >= 500: result = "A server error occurred"
      Case Is >= 400: result = "A client error occurred"
      Case Is >= 300: result = "A redirection occurred"
      Case Is >= 200: result = "Success"
      Case Is >= 100: result = "Information"
      Case Is > 0: result = result & vbNewLine & "An inofficial error occoured"
      Case Is < 0: result = result & vbNewLine & "An inofficial error occoured"
      Case Else: result = "An error without server status occured: " & result
    End Select
    
    If state <> 0 Then
      ' Add details
      result = result & vbNewLine & "HTTP status: " & .Status
      result = result & vbNewLine & "HTTP status text: " & .statusText  ' This line don't work for .statusText but I don't know why
    End If
    
    ' Do here what you want with the result
    MsgBox result
  End With
End Sub


12007 is not an HTTP status code - it's a WININET error code, meaning "The server name could not be resolved", identifying that a route to the host could not be found before even using HTTP. Sadly this is not documented.
